# How do return the count of a particular field in psql db

Tags: postgresql, relational-database, sequelize.js

I have a database tables with the relationships as below.

```
Cagetory ---> CategorItems //One to many(CategoryItem has categoryId colum)
CatgeoryItems ---> Post // One to many(Post has categoryItemId).
```

I want to count the total number of records in `Post` groupBy the `categoryItemId` also returning along the `categoryItem` name, and the `categoryName`. I want columns like returned

```
CategoryName, item, totalInPostTable
```

I am using sequelize rdb mapper. When i use the query below

```
models.Post.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.CategoryItem,
            attributes: ['item'],
            required: true,
            include: [{
                model: models.Category,
                attributes: ['name'],
                required: true,
                group: ["name"]
            }]
        }],
        attributes: ['categoryItemId'],
    })
```

It returns the record below

```
{
    "categoryItemId": 1,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 1,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 1,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 1,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 1,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 2,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
},
{
    "categoryItemId": 4,
    "CategoryItem": {
        "item": "xxxxxx",
        "Category": {
            "name": "xxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

However,it failed and return null without error as soon as i groupBy the categpryItem id like below.

```
 models.Post.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.CategoryItem,
            attributes: ['item', [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('id')), 'no_category']],
            required: true,
            include: [{
                model: models.Category,
                attributes: ['name'],
                required: true,
            }]
        }],
        attributes: ['categoryItemId'],

        group: ["categoryItemId"]
    })
```

Pls what am i doing wrong ? ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give me the column name in the database. Is it `categoryItemId` or `category_item_id`? Did u check the query generated from Sequelize?

Comment: @PraveenKumar its `categoryItemId `

Comment: What about the query generated from sequelize?